# Trying to use pointer notation instead of array notation on this test scores program but I'm stuck

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Ok so I have this assignment where I write a program that the user enters test scores and them I sort them into ascending order. But it also asks to change array notation to pointer notation. Below is my code. It runs but it has all array notation. Please help!

```
#include <iostream> //libraries
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std; //standard

void arrSelectSort( double*, int ); //prototypes
void showArr( double* arr, int size ) //array
{
    for( int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
    cout << setw(8) << arr[i];
}
int main() //main function No array boxes allowed
{
   int numTests; //declare variable
   cout << "How many test scores would you like to enter? " << endl; //ask user how many test scores they want to enter
   cin >> numTests; //user input
   cin.sync();

   double* testScores = new double[numTests]; //pointer?

   cout << "Enter the test scores below:" << endl; //ask user to input test scores
   double  sumTestScores = 0.0; //declare variable
   for( int super = 0; super < numTests; ++super ) //super is inheritance
   {
      cout << "Test Score " << (super + 1) //inheritance
           << ": " << endl;
      cin >> testScores[super]; //Need to rid of this array notation
      cin.sync();
      sumTestScores += testScores[super]; //need to get rid of the array notation
    }

   cout << "You entered testScores: " << endl; //show results
   cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2); //show results
   showArr( testScores, numTests);

   cout << "The test scores sorted in ascending order are: " << endl; //show tests in ascending order
   arrSelectSort( testScores, numTests ); // show ascending
   showArr( testScores, numTests );

   cout << "The average score is " << sumTestScores / numTests << endl; //show average test score

   delete [] testScores; // free memory
   testScores = 0; // make testScores point to null

   char c; //safe exit
   cout << "Please hit any key and <ENTER> to continue..." << endl;
   cin >> c; //user input
   return 0; //exit
}
void arrSelectSort( double* arr, int size ) //ascending order sort
{
    int startScan; //declare variables
    double minIndex; // declare variables
    double minElem; // declare variables

    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++) //loop for scores
    {
        minIndex = startScan; //pointer?
        minElem = arr[startScan]; //no array
        for(int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++) //ascending loop sort
        {
            if (arr[index] < minElem) //
            {
                minElem = arr[index]; //
                minIndex = index; //
            }
        }
        arr[(int)minIndex] = arr[startScan]; //
        arr[startScan] = minElem;//
    }
}
```

// I have tried declaring the arrays and changing them to pointers but it won't run
//This program runs but has a line spacing problem

Comment: `arr[i]` is equivalent to `*(arr + i)`.

Comment: off topic: `double minIndex` is assigned nothing but `int`s and is cast to int the only time it is used. Why is this a `double`? and `int startScan; //declare variables` the comment raises a "No <expletive deleted>, Sherlock." response. It adds nothing of value and actually makes you look kind of stupid. I recommend not commenting the brutally obvious stuff.

Comment: "super is inheritance", errr..., what now?

Comment: `arr[i]` is equivalent to `*(arr + i)` is equivalent to `*(i + arr)` is equivalent to `i[arr]`.

Answer (score 0):

`array[index]` is equivalent to `*(array + index)`, so replace one with the other.